# Inherited attributes in bison/yacc

Tags: bison

How can I use inherited attributes in bison/yacc ? 
Say, I have a grammar like this -
program -> stmts

What I wanted to do is in bison : 
program : stmts {$$.next = newLabel();  $1.next = $$.next; }

Here next is an attribute declared in a structure and that type is added to union.

Answer (score 5):

You can sometimes use [mid-rule actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Mid_002dRule-Actions) to simulate top-down traverse during bottom-up parsing, but by far the cleanest and most flexible approach is to fill in attributes in the AST after the initial parse, using whatever combination of tree walks seem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In [btyacc](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/btyacc) you can use:

```
program: stmts(newLabel()) { $$.next = $1.next; }

stmts($arg) : .... { $$.next = $arg; ... }
```

to do this sort of thing.  This is equivalent to

```
program: { $<tag>$ = newLabel()); } stmts { $$.next = $1.next; }

stmts: .... { $$.next = $<tag>0; ... }
```

in bison (or yacc), but more type-safe.  You'll need the right `%union` and `%type` declarations in either case.